# MSI can't register DLLs when built with Windows 8 vs Windows 7

Tags: windows-8, windows-7, windows-installer, dllregistration

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to build a MSI consisting of several DLL files set to register using vsdrpCOMSelfReg. There are also several Windows services that are installed using custom actions. My target machine is running Windows 32bit embedded standard.

My previous development box ran Windows 7 64 bit and I could build and install this MSI with no problem. I recently changed over to Windows 8 Pro, and when I build the MSI using the exact same code base I get "failed to register" errors on my DLLs, which then causes the services to fail installing.

I have a "Privileged" launch condition in the MSI that passes for both versions, so it looks like the required permissions are there.

If I set the DLL files to "vsdrpCOM" I can successfully register after the fact using regsvr32, but my services can't install because they rely on those DLLs being registered to complete their own installation.

What am I missing? What changed with DLL registry beween Windows 7 and Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

The usual cause for this is missing dependencies. ComSelfReg requires your Dlls to load and run during the install. If you have included the VC++ runtime support as merge modules and they install in WinSxS then they are not available until after your selfreg code needs to run. The symptoms are exactly those you'd get when the VC++ runtime is being installed from merge modules and do not already exist on the system - failure during the install and success with regsvr32 after the install.

In general you should look at using a tool that doesn't require code to install services. All the major install tools populate the ServiceInstall and ServiceControl tables in the MSI file because MSI will install services just fine, but VS setups don't use them for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I'm going to avoid using ComSelfReg in the future. In my case this wasn't the issue, but I appreciate the best practice advice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the dependencies automatically pulled in when I added the DLL Project Outputs. One of the detected dependencies was IPHLPAPI.DLL, pulled from C:\Windows\System32. This DLL was then copied into the application directory. In my install of Windows 8 Pro, IPHLPAPI.DLL is version 6.2.9200.16420. In Windows 7, this file is version 6.1.7600.16385.

I'm guessing my assemblies were referencing the Windows 8 version since that was in the local directory, and this caused registration and/or runtime errors. I excluded IPHLPAPI.DLL from the installer and everything is now running correctly, referencing the file in System32.